# Two's Complement, subtracting two negative binary numbers

Tags: java, math, binary, subtraction

So I'm doing CS and the lecturer wrote out a new binary question that I can't wrap my head around.

Basically, how do you subtract two negative numbers if they are in binary?

Specifically how to do it using Two's Constant which was just introduced.

For example: `-2 - -7 = 5`
Or: `1110 - 1001`

I don't understand how you use those bits to get the correct answer, I.e. 5.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: the same way you do regular subtraction? or are you asking about the rules when you overflow the leftmost bit?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I really don't understand how? If I switch the 2nd term and add them, I'm left with the number 1 even after overflow. Would you mind showing me the working for an example?

Comment: Potentially try here? http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
  1110 -2
- 1001 -7
------
  0101  5
```

and this is the same as

```
  1110 -2
+ 0111  7
------
  0101  5
```

Comment: Thank you! So, the answer is 10101 - Then because of overflow you get rid of the left-most digit to make it 0101, i.e. 5?

Comment: @alexjackhughes yes, if you use 4-bit or 8-bit or 32-bit values, you don't get an extra bit because you performed a calculation. (Technically the CPU does keep this bit in flags but Java ignores them)